# Is it alright to execute long operation on main thread in this scenario

Tags: multithreading, swift, synchronization

I'm using Parse to access application data, my goal is to check if user already applied.

```
func buttonApplyClicked() {
    if (userAlreadyApplied()==false) {
        // gather data and register the user
    }
}

func userAlreadyApplied() {
    // executing on main thread will block
    let applicant = parseQueryInstance.getFirstObject()
    return applicant != nil
    // or
    parseQueryInstance.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() {
        // check data and return result
    }
}
```

So if use asynchronous call i lose the main thread, if i use synchronous call i get warning that i execute long operation.

I guess its alright to execute this operation on the main thread, also i suppose its alright to execute the registering operation in the main thread too, am i thinking good?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess its alright to execute this [long-running] operation on the main thread

This is never true in a Cocoa app. You must never block the main thread.

Cocoa development often requires asynchronous operations. You have to deal with the fact that you won't always have answers immediately and will have to update when you have the answer. You also must deal with the fact that your requests may fail. The network cannot be assumed to be fast or available.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases, execute a long operation is not recommended. You should execute in another thread, then use delegate pattern or completion handler to invoke main thread again. During this time, if the operation takes time and it must finish before another operations, you should display a waiting message.